# How can I serialise data history in Immutable.js to enable time travel?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, trie

For a TypeScript/JavaScript project I am working on I need some kind of time-travel enabled data structure with full persistence. That data structure needs to be able to be serialised to a database or at least the file system. I want to be able to branch off old versions for modifications but I don't need to do anything fancy like merge branches. I figure I need some kind of HAMT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie) such as that implemented within Immutable.js. I however also need the ability to save the internal structure to a database or to disk. Most people use Immutable.js when diffing data structures such as when working out whether to update a React component which is a very useful property. What I need from it however is time travel and serialization so nodes are stored efficiently and all history is preserved. Both these things are properties of a HAMT however Immutable.js appears not to support this. Perhaps I am missing something in the docs. Is this possible with Immutable.js? If not does anybody know any libraries I can use to accomplish this? Do I have to implement my own HAMT?

---

### UPDATE:

To be clear I need to serialise the internal data structure not a representation of it. From what I can tell that means I need some kind of hash table keeping track of each node. As we are talking about a persistent data structure I only want to serialise new nodes as they are written upon mutations and I do not want to serialise the entire data tree or a representation of it.

I know I can simply take the output for any operation from Immutable.js and save a serialised copy of that data as if I were using it in Redux with Redux Dev Tools. The problem is that will create too much traffic over the wire and cause our data storage requirements to blow out and is not what I really need in this situation.

Comment: I'll admit to being ignorant on data time travel, but the wiki page on HAMT doesn't seem to imply that time travel and serialization are innate properties of a HAMT. Perhaps there is some implementation of a HAMT that you're used to that has those features?

Comment: To be honest I admit perhaps I am making an assumption about HAMTs however my understanding is that Immutable JS achieves its immutability by only adding nodes to the hash trie and returning a new root node calculated from each parent node of any leaf modification operation. By collecting a list of root nodes you have time travel as well as economic data storage. Git works in a similar way. Immutable.js uses HAMTs so I am assuming they have that property. I too am no expert but am struggling to find a lib that supports serialisation.

Comment: Did you find a solution to do this?

Answer (score -2):

There are two questions here.

> How can I take advantage of time travel in Immutable.js?

Immutable.js doesn't natively implement time travel, but the nature of the library's data structures (any modification returns a new reference to that 'snapshot' of the data) makes it very easy to implement yourself. All you need to do is create a 'history container' or wrapper over your data structure, which automatically stores each new reference created by Immutable in a map. Then you'll be able to undo/redo, and search the map for specific times. There is a sample implementation using a Proxy in [this free preview](https://books.google.com/books?id=2JlGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA35) of a book by Adam Boduch on Google Books. You can, of course, modify it to your needs.

> How can I serialize data in Immutable.js?

The de facto serialization technique in JavaScript is `toJSON()`. Immutable.js implements `toJSON()` for every data structure it offers. From the [readme](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/blob/9af3105bb507fb389758c01189ba81cb33b5bad2/README.md):

> All Immutable.js Collections can be converted to plain JavaScript Arrays and Objects shallowly with toArray() and toObject() or deeply with toJS(). All Immutable Collections also implement toJSON() allowing them to be passed to JSON.stringify directly. They also respect the custom toJSON() methods of nested objects.

You can convert from JSON back to an Immutable structure by deserializing with `JSON.parse(data)` and passing it to the constructor or using `.fromJS()` in any Immutable structure.

Comment: Making copies of the serialised data will soon become unwieldy as I need to serialise the history of the data along with the current state. What I need is to serialise the internal data structure to save each node with its hash key and only save the node once in the database or file system. I will update the question to make this clear.